# If a card were to have every keyword created, what would the order of them be?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, game-design

I've looked around and haven't been able to find a complete answer so I'll ask in case anyone has an answer or can point me to one.

I know the order isn't alphabetical, the keywords usually appear in a specific order. Take [Akroma](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=106645) and [Sphinx of the Steel Wind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=189641) for example, which puts the keyword order as:

flying, first strike, vigilance, trample, haste, and protection for Akroma

and

flying, first strike, vigilance, lifelink, and protection for the Sphinx.

As with both, it goes flying, first strike vigilance, then some other evergreen keywords, then ends with protection. So is there any distinct order that WotC follows for these?